# Death penalty convict status

Tags: halacha, marriage, death, capital-punishment

If a Jewish woman is married to a Jewish man, and she has been sentenced to death or declared a resident of a Rebellious City, but not yet been executed, is she considered technically "dead" to the extent that her marriage is terminated, and she is permitted to marry another man?

Comment: Tora Tora Tora, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for bringing your question here! You could make this question much more valuable and answerable by [edit]ing in why you suspect this may be an issue and/or why the answer to this question is significant. Also, please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Comment: Do we, in general, extend the rule “it must be destroyed, so it has the status as if it already is” to people? This question is more likely to have been discussed in the context of whether a condemned man can effect _kiddushin_.

Comment: … and the possibility of judicial reprieve is going to be a factor.

Comment: Together with the presence of the [tag:aguna] tag, which I didn't understand until now, I get the sense that you're trying to invent a scheme for freeing agunot, perhaps by convening a court to, pro forma, order their executions. I once had a similar (even less practical) notion regarding open-heart surgery. Anyway, I recommend that you either make your whole question explicit up-front or narrow the question back down to the atomic "can one marry her" question, tag accordingly, and ask additional questions separately.

Comment: The _g'mara_ lists two ways to end a marriage, and death of the wife isn't one of them. [(Nor is death of the wife the other of them.)](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/69484.html)

Comment: @msh210, Are you saying that a woman remains *mekudeshet* post-mortem, as long as her husband is alive? If that's so, wouldn't the widower, under the *Cheirem deRabbeinu Gershom*, have to get a *heter mei-a rabbanim* to remarry?

Comment: @IsaacMoses, I would have to assume _Rabenu Ger'shom_ didn't include that case in his _cherem_, in any event. As to whether she is called "_m'kudeshes_" after she dies, I don't know: I know only what I paraphrased.